# Julia missing array constructors?

Tags: arrays, julia

I have just installed julia after looking at it for a while. The interpreter and a basic hello world program works but... something is not going well if the array constructor.

I am trying to run the basic example from the documentation `A = Array{Float64, 2}(2, 2);` and I get this:

```
julia> A = Array{Float64, 2}(2, 2);
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Array{Float64,2}(::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array{Float64,2}(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64, ::Int64) where T at boot.jl:396
  Array{Float64,2}(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64...) where {T, N} at boot.jl:400
  Array{Float64,2}(::UndefInitializer, ::Integer, ::Integer) where T at sysimg.jl:143
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I realize this is a dumb question and it might very well be against the spirit of SO but google had yielded no results and this is an example copy pasted from the documentation after all.

Bottom line question: I want a plain old  2d array, what goes wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Julia v0.7 on the way to get an uninitialized array is `Array{Float64, 2}(undef, 2, 2)` (note the `undef`).

To get a preinitialized array you could for example use `fill(0., 2, 2)`.

(I guess your problem arose from reading an old version of the documentation.)

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! I read a the docs about undef. However this raises the question of *why* this was introduced. I mean the first argument is an `UndefInitializer` which is a singleton const. Correct me if I'm wrong but we have a function taking a parameter and that parameter ca literally only ever be given one particular value, `undef`. What purpose does that serve?

Comment: In addition to `undef`, that argument can also be `missing` or `nothing` if the type can hold such values.

Comment: The idea is that we will implement more array constructors like these in the future, where the first arguments always decides the content.

Comment: It also makes explicit that the array is uninitialised: previously there were cases were people got errors or unexpected results because they expected it to be zero-filled.